# Why the following c++ code keeps output "bad data, try again"?

Tags: c++, io

```
int main()
{
        int temp;
        while (cin>>temp, !cin.eof())
        {
                if (cin.bad())
                {
                        throw runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
                }

                if (cin.fail())
                {
                        cerr<<"bad data, try again";
                        cin.clear(istream::failbit);
                        continue;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

If I input `x` then `Enter`,the output will be :

> , try againbad data, try againbad
>   data, try a a, try againbad data, try
>   againbad data, try ta, try againbad
>   data, try againbad data, try ata, try
>   againbad data, try againbad data, tr
>   data, try againbad data, try againbad
>   data, t

Why?

Comment: You should replace the `while` loop with `while(cin>>temp){...}`. Should do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

The [ios::clear()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) method actually *replaces* the stream control state bits with its argument. You're setting `cin`'s control state to `fail` every time you issue `cin.clear(istream::failbit);`.

You should simply call `cin.clear();` instead, without arguments. That will reset the stream's control state to `good`.

**EDIT:** Oh my god, I forgot.

You also need to call [istream::ignore()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to discard the invalid `x` token you've just entered, since `clear()` doesn't flush pending input:

```
if (cin.fail()) {
    cerr << "bad data, try again\n";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    continue;
}
```

Comment: @fms, yup, forgot a piece of the puzzle, sorry. I guess I spend too much time using higher-level languages :) I updated my answer.

Comment: Very important to do these in order. I just spent way too long figuring this out because I was ignoring then clearing. I suppose ignore() won't work if the stream is not in a good state.

Answer (score 3):

Because `x` is not an integer, the `operator>>` operator doesn't read anything, so when you clear the bit and try again, the same thing results.

Answer (score 2):

If you use formatted input/output the data must match. `x` is not an integer. Try to enter `5` `Enter`. Or define `temp` as `std::string`.

Comment: Why it **keeps** output `bad data, try again`?

Comment: In case of failure you should go to the end of stream to read the next input. `cin.seekg(0, ios:end);`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't clear() the stream.

Comment: @fms, no, though I agree `clear()` is quite a misnomer. Welcome to C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with data still being in the input buffer. `cin.clear()` is simply clearing the error state of `cin` rather than clearing the buffer. Try doing something like this:

```
int main()
{
        int temp;
        while (cin>>temp, !cin.eof())
        {
                if (cin.bad())
                {
                        throw runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
                }

                if (cin.fail())
                {
                        cerr<<"bad data, try again";
                        cin.clear();
                        cin.sync();
                        continue;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

`cin.sync()` will effectively clear the buffer for you. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/sync/ for more information on it.

Comment: `cin.clear();` clears the fail bit of `cin`, and `cin.sync()` clears the input buffer that `cin` reads from. When you enter a non-integer value, `cin` is failing because temp is an `int`. After the failed read, you need to clear the buffer of any unread data and try again.

Comment: Why `cin.clear();cin.sync();` but `cin.clear(istream::failbit);cin.sync();` doesn't work(keeps outputing `bad data, try again`)?

Answer (score 0):

Because your loop will end only when end-of-file is reached. But if you try to read a number where there is an alpha character, cin will fail but eof will never be reached. It will fail to read the number over and over again.