# Bad data, try again

Tags: c++

I found this code fragment in a book:

```
int ival;
// read cin and test only for EOF; loop is executed even if there are other IO failures
while (cin >> ival, !cin.eof()) {
    if (cin.bad())         // input stream is corrupted; bail out
        throw runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
    if (cin.fail()) {                        // bad input
        cerr<< "bad data, try again";        // warn the user
        cin.clear(istream::failbit);         // reset the stream
        istream::iostate cin_state = cin.rdstate();
        continue;                            // get next input
    }
    // ok to process ival
}
```

If I click 'f' in the command window, then countless "bad data, try again", and cin_state is 0X02, which is equal to badbit. Failbit has not been clear, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the following c++ code keeps output "bad data, try again"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297469/why-the-following-c-code-keeps-output-bad-data-try-again)

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that `f` is never removed from the input stream, so `cin >> ival` keeps trying to read it over and over again.

You need to skip past it. See, for example, [How does istream::ignore( ) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693106/how-does-istreamignore-work)

Comment: I got your answer, but when I use `cin.ignore(1000, '\n');`, problem appear again. When I use `cin.clear();` instead of 'cin.clear(istream::failbit);', "bad data, try again" only occurred once. I think  `cin.clear();` cleared the fail state, but 'cin.clear(istream::failbit);' didn't, I can't explain why.

Comment: @Robert `cin.clear()` is correct, please see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

While NPE's point about not removing the offending data from the stream is correct, it's not the only (or most egregious) problem.

You should be using `cin.clear()`, which is the same as `cin.clear(ios_base::goodbit)` due to a default argument. As you speculated in your comment, `cin.clear(istream::failbit)` does not reset `cin` to the good state. In fact, **it sets the stream to the failed state**. This may seem counterintuitive, but `clear` sets the state of the stream to (or "clears it to") the passed parameter. There are some other details in regards to its operation, but they aren't germane to this discussion.

Make sure you call `clear` before `ignore`, otherwise the latter will have no effect. Finally, to protect against arbitrarily long invalid entries, pass `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` to `ignore` as the first parameter.

The modified code fragment should be:

```
int ival;
// read cin and test only for EOF; loop is executed even if there are other IO failures
while (cin >> ival, !cin.eof()) {
    if (cin.bad())         // input stream is corrupted; bail out
        throw runtime_error("IO stream corrupted");
    if (cin.fail()) {                        // bad input
        cerr<< "bad data, try again";        // warn the user
        cin.clear();         // or cin.clear(istream::goodbit);
        istream::iostate cin_state = cin.rdstate();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        continue;                            // get next input
    }
    // ok to process ival
}
```

As to why you found this in C++ Primer, I can't say. I haven't read the book, but I know it's fairly well thought of. I'd suggest checking how old your edition is and looking for an errata list.