# How to clear IO state?

Tags: c++

When I read C++ Primer 8.2, I write codes to pass illegal data. It is strange that I have to clear istream::eofbit while eof() is false;

when I run `./a.out < test.data`.

The data **loops forever** to print `bad data, try again.`

`$ cat test.data`

`1 a 2`

Here is my code

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <stdexcept>
  3 using namespace std;
  4 
  5 istream& getData(istream &is) {
  6 
  7     int num;
  8 
  9     try {
 10     while (is >> num, !is.eof()) {
 11         if (is.bad()) {
 12             throw std::runtime_error("IO stream corrupted.");
 13         }
 14 
 15         if (is.fail()) {
 16 //            cout << "fail " << is.eof() << endl;
 17 //           break;
 18             cerr << "bad data, try again." << endl;
 19             is.clear(istream::failbit); // can not clear eofbit which leads to loop forever
 20             is.clear(istream::eofbit);
 21             is.ignore(200, ' ');
 22             continue;
 23         }
 24 
 25         cout << num << " ";
 26     }
 27     } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
 28         cerr << "IO Exception." << endl;
 29     }
 30 
 31     cout << endl;
 32 
 33     is.clear();
 34     return is;
 35 }
 36 
 37 int main() {
 38 
 39     istream& is2 = getData(cin);
 40 
 41 //    getData(is2);
 42 
 43     return 0;
 44 }
```

Why should I have to clear `istream::eofbit` in `line 20`, while I tested that `is.eof()` is `false` in line 16?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the following c++ code keeps output "bad data, try again"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297469/why-the-following-c-code-keeps-output-bad-data-try-again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::basic_ios::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function is kind of wrongly named in my opinion. It actuallt *sets* the flag you pass to it.

To clear e.g. everything, you don't actually have to pass any flags, it defaults to `std::ios_base::goodbit`.

Comment: "is kind of wrongly named": yes and no.  The error isn't in the name, as much as it is in allowing the argument.

Comment: It seems that `is.clear(istream::failbit)` doesn't work at all when `is` is in bad state. Only `is.clear()` works.